# React: open page in new tab with state

Tags: reactjs, parameters, onclick, window.open

I would like my dynamic component to open in a new tab so I can leave the results from a search available on the initial page. The component that I would like to open a new page will need to have multiple properties carried over from the parent.

I tried using window.open() with my onClick handler. This will open the new tab, but don't carry over the properties from the parent state that are needed. I tried using localStorage.setItem(), but this is too hacky and would only work based on the users broweser settings.

This is the onclick method that creates a new page. I would like to be able to have it open a new tab from here.

```
 handleContract = (id) => {
  API.openRow(id)
  .then(res => {
    const pdfs = res.data;
    this.setState({pdfs});
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/pdf',
      state: { labels:this.state.labels,
        pdfs:this.state.pdfs,
        titles:this.state.titles }
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  API.titles(id)
  .then(res => {
    const titles = res.data;
    this.setState({titles});
  })
}
```

As a secondary option. Would it be possible to have a modal pop up on my onClick method and display the component that way?

Answer (score 4):

You can't really pass state between two windows or tabs. You need pass param from URL and fetch data using some api using that param

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? How does one pass param from URL and fetch?

Comment: while defining your routes, you can do something like this `<Route exact path="/someroute/:someparam" component={Component} />` and inside the `<Component />` you can get someparam by using `this.props.match.params.someparam` and use that param for your server side login to obtain whatever results you want

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it is a new applcation instance we need to carry over the data manually somehow. I myself never did do that but you could try to use more traditional ways like query strings/url parameters (if you don't have too many information), or you could use window.postMessage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

But it seems like that there is also a way to archive what yo u want with an React portal. Since, like I said, I never did something like this myself I hope it is okay if I share a link to an medium article which explains how to do it:
https://hackernoon.com/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202